# Group and identify busiest time periods

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a log file that's just date in one column and time in the other. I'm trying to find the most popular time periods.

```
Date          Time
Jan/01/2017   08:23:45
Jan/01/2017   15:54:21 
Jan/02/2017   04:02:39 
Jan/03/2017   06:33:12
...
```

I'm looking for an efficient way to group the data into 10-minute portions and then find the most popular 1-hour-intervals. So it's very likely the most popular hour-long-intervals would be consecutive like:

```
Interval               Count
08:10:00 - 09:10:00    586
08:20:00 - 09:20:00    565
08:30:00 - 09:30:00    544
...
```

This has to scale up well to GB of data and I need to be able to find the most popular intervals preferably without sorting the entire table.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert to minutes since midnight, use integer division and a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). No need to sort the data, this should work fine and be efficient :

```
from collections import Counter

log = """Jan/01/2017   08:23:45
Jan/01/2017   15:54:21
Jan/01/2017   15:50:21
Jan/01/2017   15:52:21
Jan/02/2017   04:02:39
Jan/03/2017   06:33:12"""

portion = 10
interval = 60

counter = Counter()

for line in log.split("\n"):
    time = line.split()[-1]
    hour, minute, second = map(int, time.split(':'))
    since_midnight = hour * 60 + minute
    counter[since_midnight // portion] += 1

for slot, count in counter.most_common():
    print("%02d:%02d -> %02d:%02d - %d" % ((slot * portion) / 60,
                                           (slot * portion) % 60,
                                           ((slot + 1) * portion) / 60,
                                           ((slot + 1) * portion) % 60,
                                           count))
```

It outputs :

```
15:50 -> 16:00 - 3
04:00 -> 04:10 - 1
08:20 -> 08:30 - 1
06:30 -> 06:40 - 1
```

Since you didn't write any code, I'll leave an exercise to you : for a given 10-minute portion, increment the counter of every 60-min interval containing this portion. A simple for loop should do.

Also, you should read the file line by line. The `split("\n")` was just for a simple example.